# Sum of an array using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[
   {
      "ProductId": 177,
      "Quantity": 3,
      "Price": 1,
      "OriginalPrice": 1,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 3,
      "SoldPrice": 1,
      "ProductName": "Hand Spinners"
   },
   {
      "ProductId": 30207,
      "Quantity": 2,
      "Price": 525,
      "OriginalPrice": 525,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 1050,
      "SoldPrice": 525,
      "ProductName": "Clay Home"
   }
]
```

I want to calculate sum of all 'OriginalPricetotal' in an array using javascript / Jquery. I tried few types . But that is not working .

Comment: `I tried few types` - Please share your attempt.

Comment: hint: `map` + `reduce`

Comment: I think simple `reduce` will do

Comment: sure, but with map it's sexier and shorter :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through the array and get the value of `OriginalPricetotal` to add and get the sum. Since, the value is already a number and not a string, you do not need `parseInt()` to parse the values before addition:

**USING forEach()**

```js
var arr = [
   {
      "ProductId": 177,
      "Quantity": 3,
      "Price": 1,
      "OriginalPrice": 1,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 3,
      "SoldPrice": 1,
      "ProductName": "Hand Spinners"
   },
   {
      "ProductId": 30207,
      "Quantity": 2,
      "Price": 525,
      "OriginalPrice": 525,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 1050,
      "SoldPrice": 525,
      "ProductName": "Clay Home"
   }
];

var sum = 0;
arr.forEach(function(obj){
  sum += obj.OriginalPricetotal;
});

console.log(sum);
```

**USING map()**

```js
var arr = [
   {
      "ProductId": 177,
      "Quantity": 3,
      "Price": 1,
      "OriginalPrice": 1,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 3,
      "SoldPrice": 1,
      "ProductName": "Hand Spinners"
   },
   {
      "ProductId": 30207,
      "Quantity": 2,
      "Price": 525,
      "OriginalPrice": 525,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 1050,
      "SoldPrice": 525,
      "ProductName": "Clay Home"
   }
];

var sum = 0;
arr.map((obj)=>{sum += obj.OriginalPricetotal});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Should we not close this post as dupe instead?

Comment: Also, `.map` implementation is just wrong

Answer (score 3):

Please see below snippet which will return you the answer you want

```js
var obj = [
   {
      "ProductId": 177,
      "Quantity": 3,
      "Price": 1,
      "OriginalPrice": 1,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 3,
      "SoldPrice": 1,
      "ProductName": "Hand Spinners"
   },
   {
      "ProductId": 30207,
      "Quantity": 2,
      "Price": 525,
      "OriginalPrice": 525,
      "OriginalPricetotal": 1050,
      "SoldPrice": 525,
      "ProductName": "Clay Home"
   }
];

var ans = 0;
// Better option
obj.forEach(function(value){
 ans = ans + value.OriginalPricetotal
});
console.log(ans);

ans = 0;
//obj.map(o => ans = ans + o.OriginalPricetotal); //ES6
obj.map(function(value){
 ans = ans + value.OriginalPricetotal
});
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: `.map` without a return statement and assignment of final value is just a bad implementation. Please use `.forEach` instead. Also, though this is opinionated comment, answering a question without effort promotes spoon feeding

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks. Ya forEach is better option. Let me add it in my answer too.

Comment: Still, `.map` implementation is wrong